# Shiny Plotly R - When Toggling Between Graphs, Maintain Zoom

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, r-plotly

I have a shiny app that I'm graphing multiple ggplot2 scatterplots with plotly. How do I keep the zoom fixed when I switch between scatterplots?

I'm looking for something like this, but for Shiny Plotly R: https://community.plot.ly/t/preserving-ui-state-like-zoom-in-dcc-graph-with-uirevision/15793

EDIT:

I am currently trying to implement [plotlyProxy()](https://plot.ly/r/plotlyproxy/), but so far have been unsuccessful.

This is what I currently have (superfluous code has been deleted):

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {


  output$trendPlot <- renderPlotly({

    # build graph with ggplot syntax
    p <- ggplot()

    zoom <- event_data("plotly_relayout","source")

    observeEvent(lims(), {
      plotlyProxy("plot", session) %>%
        plotlyProxyInvoke("relayout", list(xaxis.range = list(zoom$`xaxis.range[0]`,zoom$`xaxis.range[1]`),
                                           yaxis.range = list(zoom$`yaxis.range[0]`,zoom$`yaxis.range[1]`)))
    })

  })


}
```

But it doesn't do anything. The graph still resets the x-axis and y-axis when I toggle to a different scatterplot...

Comment: One approach in Shiny would be to use [plotlyProxy()](https://plot.ly/r/plotlyproxy/) to avoid re-rendering the plot (which resets the zoom).

Comment: I have been finagling with plotlyProxy() for the past hour and I haven't been able to figure out how to get it to stop re-rendering the plot...any pointers? @ismirsehregal thanks for your help!

Comment: My comment was aiming at the possibility of adding/removing/changing traces via plotlyProxy while your zoom remains unchanged. It was not about programmatically setting the zoom as you tried above. Try to zoom in the example plot shown on the link I provided and add/remove traces with the buttons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone interested, this was how I resolved the issue:

```
server <- function(input, output) {

output$trendPlot <- renderPlotly({

zoom <- event_data("plotly_relayout")

# build graph with ggplot syntax
if(is.null(zoom) || names(zoom[1]) %in% c("xaxis.autorange", "width") ||names(zoom[3])==c("xaxis.showspikes")) {
   p <- ggplot()
}
else{
p <- ggplot() + 
scale_y_continuous(limits=c(zoom$`yaxis.range[0]`,zoom$`yaxis.range[1]`)) +
scale_x_continuous(limits=c(zoom$`xaxis.range[0]`,zoom$`xaxis.range[1]`))
    }

  })


}
```